# How to extract year and change format to mm-dd-yyyy from yyyy/mm/dd in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Not able to extract year from this format(yyyy/mm/dd) and not able to change the format to mm-dd-yyyy . I have tried the following but failed.

```
with table1 as(
select "2017/1/1" as doj union all
select "2017/2/3" as doj union all
select "2017/3/5" as doj union all
select "2017/4/7" as doj union all
select "2017/6/9" as doj 
)
select format_date("%m-%d-%Y",doj)doj from table1


Error: No matching signature for function FORMAT_DATE for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signature: FORMAT_DATE(STRING, DATE)
```

Comment: FORMAT_DATE takes a DATE, not a STRING. Have you read the documentation for PARSE_DATE? What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS(
  SELECT "2017/1/1" AS doj UNION ALL
  SELECT "2017/2/3" AS doj UNION ALL
  SELECT "2017/3/5" AS doj UNION ALL
  SELECT "2017/4/7" AS doj UNION ALL
  SELECT "2017/6/9" AS doj 
)
SELECT 
  PARSE_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", doj) doj_as_date,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", doj)) year
FROM `project.dataset.table1`
```

Comment: Whoops, I hadn't seen the "extract year" part... (although this answer doesn't do the formatting part...)

Comment: i think your answer is still valid and there is no real reason for deleting it - I would 'undelete' it :o)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`parse_date`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date) first to parse, before you can format or extract the year. This works:

```
with table1 as(
  select "2017/1/1" as doj union all
  select "2017/2/3" as doj union all
  select "2017/3/5" as doj union all
  select "2017/4/7" as doj union all
  select "2017/6/9" as doj 
)
select
   format_date("%m-%d-%Y", parse_date("%Y/%m/%d", doj)) as doj,
   extract(YEAR from parse_date("%Y/%m/%d", doj)) as year
from table1
```

Although depending on what you're doing with the result, I'd suggest just parsing, and returning the date to the client to extract the year and reformat if they need to. I understand there are situations where that's not feasible, e.g. if you need to write a table for some other client which *really* needs the date as a string in a particular format.

If you need to format the date but get to choose the format at all though, I'd definitely use ISO-8601 rather than month-first or day-first :)